# node js and postgresql reduce Cpu usage

Tags: node.js, postgresql

In Node js i'm using  postgresql Database.while i am inserting bulk data  in DB the CPU usage  is getting  10% to 15%.

I want to reduce the cpu usage 5% to 6%.

```
function execute(count) {
    step(0);
    function step(i) {
        if (i < count) {
            client.query("INSERT INTO test1 (firstname, lastname) values($1, $2)", ['Ronald', 'McDonald'], function (err, respose) {
              //  console.log(respose);
                console.log("insert");
                step(++i);
            });
        }
        else {
            selectQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "cpu usage 5"?

Comment: Where is your data coming from? Postgres supports proper bulk inserts (see [`node-pg-copy-streams`](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-copy-streams), for example).

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL has a directive in its configuration file that can cache data

```
shared_buffers=3GB For 16 GB of RAM
```

This value is based on the amount of system RAM, which should be 20% of the RAM